# TSQLt Test in Jenkins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, jenkins, tsqlt

I'm trying to write my first TSQLt test. and Im trying to test it using Jenkins, for some reason the Test pass while im running it on MS SQL Studio but when im trying to let the Jenkins automatically running the test I get an Error:

```
DECLARE @test INT; SET @test = 91;
DECLARE @counter INT;
DECLARE @bol INT; SET @bol = 0;
SELECT @counter = COUNT(*) FROM Sales.Customers ;
SET @bol= CASE WHEN  @counter = @test THEN   0  else 1 END;

 EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals @Expected = 0, -- sql_variant
     @Actual = @bol, -- sql_variant
     @Message = '0' -- nvarchar(max)
```

and the error in Jenkins:

```
WARNING: Test failed [Test_Class].[test TEST_TEST] with message Expected: <0> but was: <91>
```

Im just trying to compare if the count is 91 or not and I want it to pass the test.

Comment: Are you certain that Jenkins is running it on the right server/database? Or that it is even running the shown sql? Mostly, I'm very confused that @bol can be 91 using this code ?!?

Comment: @deroby Im using Redgate one the sql server and redgate plugin on the jenkins , and the test plugin should run the test on Jenkins +#

Comment: I'm not familiar with those, but in each case it seems strange that the warning message says `Expected: <0> but was: <91>` while the values passed to `tSQLt.AssertEquals` are `0`, `@bol` and `0`. So, where does the `91` come from ?